# How to dynamically set IgnoreDataMemberAttribute to properties based on condition?

Tags: asp.net, serialization, c#-3.0

I have a class like this:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int SNo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to serialise this class to XML using this function:

```
public static string ToXML(object obj)
{
    DataContractSerializer _serializer = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());
    MemoryStream msMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    _serializer.WriteObject(msMemoryStream, obj);
    string xml = Encoding.Default.GetString(msMemoryStream.ToArray());
    return xml;
}
```

**I want output as XML.  If I pass a null value to any propery in TestClass, then that property should not come in the output XML.  How to do that?**

## Update:

How to dynamically set IgnoreDataMemberAttribute to Testclass properties based on condition?

Comment: It is impossible to remove attributes at runtime becase attributes get serialized when then assembly is compiled and are loaded as they are from assembly metadata. From what I know the biggest thing you can do is to alter an existing attribute (mutate his properties). In your place, I would stop using DataContractSerializer and I would get my hands dirty by starting to write my own serializer.